# How to dynamically pass arguments for a java function using variable length parameter

Tags: java, variables

Some function in java using variable length parameter. like

```
String java.lang.String.format(String format, Object... args)
```

How can dynamically pass parameter to this function?

For example

```
String fillInString(String str, ArrayList<String> token){
    return String.format(str, token[0], token[1]....);   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String fillInString(String str, ArrayList<String> token){
    return String.format(str, token.toArray(new String[token.size()]));   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

send the token value to the function as an array.

```
String fillInString(String str, String ... token){
    return String.format(str, token);
}
```

var args like this can accept seperate arguments or an array.